# Bacon/pork fat to replace shortening in rolls?

Tags: pork, fat, shortening

I don't have shortening and was wondering what pork fat would do to the texture of my crusty rolls?  Can pork or bacon fat be used to replace shortening in rolls?

Comment: What ratios are we talking about? Please [edit] your post to include the recipe.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, it make give it a  smokey but pleasant after taste but I in some ways prefer it to commercial lard. All bacon fat is, is a type of lard anyways done with typical dry heat such as a skillet or pan. It is arguably the best replacement you can use when making such dishes.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, animal fats such as lard or rendered bacon fat may be substituted for shortening. Really, shortening is a substitute for animal fats in the first place!

Lard and bacon fat do have a lower melting temperature than shortening, but for a kneaded dough, rather than a pastry dough, which is what I'm assuming you mean when you say "rolls," this difference is immaterial.